# record mp3 with arrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, audio, websocket

I try a lot of things with Stackoverflow and I can't get it . So I try to record audio from raspberry pi with nodejs (1). After this stream goes through a websocket server(I don't put this code because it's just a redirection). And last a websocket in vuejs listen the stream. And after I want to record this stream in mp3 (2). But I have noise or nothing.
1 - Raspberry pi :

```
ai = new audio.AudioIO({
        inOptions: {
          channelCount: 1,
          sampleFormat: audio.SampleFormat16Bit,
          sampleRate: 44100,
          deviceId: 6, // Use -1 or omit the deviceId to select the default device
          closeOnError: true // Close the stream if an audio error is detected, if set false then just log the error
        }
      });

      ai.on('data', buf => {
      
      clientAudioWebsocket.send(buf)
      }
      );
      
     
      ai.start();
```

2- Part vuejs

- Socket :

  ```
   this.dataBuffer = []

     var self = this

     var connectionToLocalServer = new WebSocket("ws://"+ip  +":4444")
     connectionToLocalServer.binaryType = "arraybuffer"

      connectionToLocalServer.onmessage = function(event) {
          self.dataBuffer.push(event.data);

      }
      connectionToLocalServer.onopen = function(event) {


    }
  ```
- part arraybuffer to mp3

  ```
    concatArrayBuffers (bufs) {
                            var offset = 0;
                            var bytes = 0;
                            var bufs2=bufs.map(function(buf,total){
                                bytes += buf.byteLength;
                                return buf;
                            });
                            var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(bytes);
                            var store = new Uint8Array(buffer);
                            bufs2.forEach(function(buf){
                                store.set(new Uint8Array(buf.buffer||buf,buf.byteOffset),offset);
                                offset += buf.byteLength;
                            });
                            return buffer }



            this.tmpResult = this.concatArrayBuffers(this.dataBuffer);

            var mp3Data = [];

            var mp3encoder = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(1, 44100, 128);

            var mp3Tmp = mp3encoder.encodeBuffer(this.tmpResult, 0, Math.floor(this.tmpResult.byteLength / 2)); 
          //Push encode buffer to mp3Data variable
            mp3Data.push(mp3Tmp);

            // Get end part of mp3
            mp3Tmp = mp3encoder.flush();

            // Write last data to the output data, too
            // mp3Data contains now the complete mp3Data
            mp3Data.push(mp3Tmp);
  ```

And I don't understand why I have arraybuffer with 16384 size buffer.
I'm really open to any solution, but I don't want to do it on server side.
Thanks

Comment: About _"why I have arraybuffer with 16384 size"_ what are the very first incoming  two bytes values? `array[0]=` **255**, and `array[0]=` **251**? If yes, then your `arrayBuffer` might be already in MP3 format and that would explain your noise output from Lame encoder.

Comment: @VC.One. Thanks for your answer, I'll check tomorrow. But I don't think this is the issue. Because when I record from server arraybuffer to a wav file there's no problem. I think it's probably a problem when I concat arrayBuffers and after how I use lamejs. But I'll check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found solution and it's because I didn't create an Int16Array :-( (sometimes it'll be better to go outside 1 hour and after you'll find the solution )

The solution is :

```
let tmpResult = this.concatArrayBuffers(this.dataBuffer)
     
var samples = new Int16Array(tmpResult);
var buffer = [];
var mp3enc = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(1, 44100, 128);
var remaining = samples.length;
var maxSamples = 1152;
for (var i = 0; remaining >= maxSamples; i += maxSamples) {
     var mono = samples.subarray(i, i + maxSamples);
     var mp3buf = mp3enc.encodeBuffer(mono);
     if (mp3buf.length > 0) {
         buffer.push(new Int8Array(mp3buf));
        }
        remaining -= maxSamples;
}
var d = mp3enc.flush();
if(d.length > 0){
 buffer.push(new Int8Array(d));
}

console.log('done encoding, size=', buffer.length);
var blob = new Blob(buffer, {type: 'audio/mp3'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate here -> https://github.com/charlielee/mp3-stream-recorder
I recommend this. At some point I'll make a nice GUI web app to do this rather than relying on cronjob.
Usage

Run the following in a terminal window or as a cronjob:

$ node index.js -s "http://firewall.pulsradio.com" -d 20000 -o "./shows"

Note: if running this as a cronjob, node and index.js need to be absolute paths to their respective locations.
Arguments

```
-s The URL of the stream to record (default http://firewall.pulsradio.com)
-d The duration in milliseconds to record for (default 5000)
-o The output directory of the file (default ./shows)
```

IFTTT Support

The following arguments can also be supplied, in order to trigger an IFTTT Webhook applet each time a recording finishes.

```
--ifttt_event The Event Name entered on the Webhook applet
--ifttt_key The user's IFTTT Webhooks key
```